# spec_helper.rbでSorceryのincludeができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sorcery

request specでログイン状態でしか呼べないアクションのテストをしようとしています。

そのため、公式を参考に、まずはspec_helper.rbでincludeを行おうと下記のコードを書きました。

spec_helper.rb

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Request, type: :request
end
```

しかし、ここのincludeでuninitialized constantのエラーが出てしまいます。

実際のエラー

```
Failure/Error: config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Sorcery
```

Gemfileではsorceryをグローバルで読み込み、アプリケーション上でもsorceryを使ったログインは問題なく行えています。
テストでのみ読み込めていない状態です。

この場合どういった原因が考えられるでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスをいただきたいと思います。

参考：
公式wiki
https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/wiki/Testing-Rails
https://qiita.com/ekusuy/items/8ab68e5731e7a6fb0123

Comment: Gemfileのsorceryの箇所はどうなっていますか？test環境でgemが読み込めていないのかも？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
こちら、"config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Request, type: :request"をrails_helperに書くことで解決できました。

Comment: そうですか。良かったですね。解決したら自分で回答を書いておいたほうがいいですよ。同じ問題で悩む人が出てくるかもしれないので。